# Is it possible to make a nested ordered list in a table of contents in Jupyter Notebook using markdown?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

Is it possible to make a nested ordered list in a table of contents in Jupyter Notebook using markdown?
I am converting python into .ipynb using [this](https://github.com/remykarem/python2jupyter).

My python code:

```py
# 1. hello
#    1.1 hello
#    1.2 hello
#        1.2.1 hello
# 1. hello
#    1. hello
#       1. hello
```

Here is my markdown cell:

```
1. hello<br>
   1.1 hello<br>
   1.2 hello<br>
       1.2.1 hello<br>
1. hello<br>
   1. hello<br>
      1. hello
```

When run it produces this:

[image]

How can I have the same effect of the second list but  with numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Markdown does not support this type of list. Here is a possible workaround (based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143029/709028) post):

Note that list items must be escaped with `\` with the exception of the nested values. This seems to be required in the notebook but not in Stack Overflow.

```markdown
* 1\. hello
   * 1.1. hello
   * 1.2. hello
       * 1.2.1. hello
* 2\. hello
   * 1\. hello
      * 1.1. hello
```

Which produces this:

- 1. hello

  - 1.1. hello
  - 1.2. hello

    - 1.2.1. hello
- 2. hello

  - 1. hello

    - 1.1. hello

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a nested ordered list is possible in Markdown (as a code block)
To produce a code block in Markdown, simply indent every line of the block by at least 4 spaces or 1 tab.

Here is my Markdown cell:

```html
    1. hello
        1.1 hello
        1.2 hello
            1.2.1. hello
    2. hello
        2.1. hello
            2.1.1. hello
```