# How can I write a nested ordered list in markdown in the below format

Tags: markdown, nested-lists

[image]

Can we write a nested ordered list in above format?
I have tried [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85474/how-to-write-nested-numbered-lists) as well, but it doesn't seem good practice. Is there any other alternative for this?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown nesting list problem at third level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66729964/markdown-nesting-list-problem-at-third-level)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make a nested ordered list in a table of contents in Jupyter Notebook using markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61540595/354577)

Answer (score 1):

Markdown doesn't support the "1.1.1" type list you wanted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).